# How to convert user input into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to write a python program that asks the user to input 7 numbers. This input should be converted into a list and display the individual numbers first, and then display the list as a whole. So my thought was i'd start with a for loop.

```
for a in range(1,8):
    number = int(input("please enter a number"))
    b = [a]
    print(b)
```

So it should look like this:

```
please enter number: 4
4
please enter number: 14
14
please enter number: 25
25
```

(repeat 4 more times)

And in the end:

```
Your list is: [4, 14, 25, ...]
```

Comment: third line : shouldn't it be "b= [number]" instead ?

Comment: why do you want to transform each individual number into a list ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []

for a in range(1,8):
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    result.append(number)

print(result)
```

A sample output is like:

```
please enter a number: 1
please enter a number: 2
please enter a number: 3
please enter a number: 4
please enter a number: 5
please enter a number: 6
please enter a number: 7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Numbers = []

for a in range (1,8):
    number = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
    Numbers.append(number)
    print(number)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't need to display a list every time (see my comment):

```
b = []
for a in range(7):
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    b.append(number)
    print(number)
print (b)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you're fairly new to Python or otherwise unfamiliar with the built-in data structures. It's always obligatory to recommend [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), though, if you're new to computer programming, and not just Python's data structures, there are [other resources](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) that are valuable to learning, as well.

For the most complete answer to the question, which includes string formatting and escape sequences, this method will get the exact output.

```
def collect_user_input():
    list_of_numbers = []
    for x in range(7):
        number = int(input("Enter a Number: "))
        list_of_numbers.append(number)
        print("\nYour number was: %d\n" % number)
    print("Your list is: \n", list_of_numbers)

collect_user_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get all numbers in one go:

```
nums = input("Please input space seperated numbers - as much as you need: ")
splitted = list(map(int, (x for x in nums.split() if x.isdigit()) ) )

print(splitted)
```

Output for input `"5 4 55 6 asdf 923 7.23"`:

```
Please input space seperated numbers - as much as you need: 5 4 55 6 asdf 923 7.23
[5, 4, 55, 6, 923]
```

This drops any non-integer inputs being inputted automatically and converts the rest to integers.

You can limit the parsed numbers f.e. by:

```
splitted = splitted[:7]  # 7 numbers at most - might be less - you need to check with if
```

Doku:

- [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)
- [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

---

Explanation for `list(map(int, (x for x in nums.split() if x.isdigit()) ) )`:

- creates a list

  - from applying `int()`

    - to each element of `split()` of your input

      - only if the splitted part `x` is `True` if tested with `isdigit()`

Answer (score -1):

```
l1=[]  
for i in range(1,11):  
  inp=int(input("enter a number"))  
  l1.append(inp)  
print(l1)
```