# How do i store an input as an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
array=[]
for i in range(5):
    array=input("Enter a number")
print(array)
```

I need to ask the user to input 5 numbers and then store them within a list, at the end I have to reverse it.

Comment: use the .append function

Comment: `array=input()` is making `array` a `str`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert user input into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195604/how-to-convert-user-input-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function, [append()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method of list. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940137/5735010) answer to know how to reverse a list.

Try this:

```
array = []
num = int(input("Enter the length of array: ")) # You need to convert str returned by input to an int using int() constructor
for i in range(num):
    array.append(input("Enter a number: ")) # You need to use append() method of list
print(array)
print(array[::-1])
```

Or

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
array = [input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(int(input("Enter the length of array: ")))]
```

To reverse a list, use

```
print(array[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an element at the end of the list you have to use `.append` method.

try this.

```
array=[]
for _ in range(5):
    array.append(input())  # use int(input()) to so that you have int type elements

print(array[::-1])  # to print array in reverse order.
```

---

You can use list comprehension here.

```
[input() for _ in range(5)][::-1]  # use int(input()) to so that you have int type elements
```