# How would I convert a str to an int?

Tags: python, string, types, integer

```
    # counter
my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n")
while my_list.isnumeric() == False:
  print("\n----------------------------------------------------")
  print("***Sorry, what you had entered contained a letter.***")
  print("----------------------------------------------------\n")

  my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n")
else:
  counter = 0 
  for item in my_list:
    counter_item = counter + item
  print(int(counter_item))
```

The exact error message is

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    counter_item = counter + item enter code here 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"
```

What should I do?

P.S (This is in Python3 on Repl.it)

Comment: [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4663306/15497888), [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2376464/15497888), [How to convert user input into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37195604/15497888)

Comment: Use the `int()` function to convert a string to int.

Comment: "How would I convert a str to an int?" The same way you did in your final call to `print`.

Comment: `isnumeric()` won't be true for a list of a integers, it will only be true if they type a single integer.

Comment: The int() is not working it just says the it is an unsupported operand.

Comment: `counter += int(item)` should not report that error.

Comment: What's the point of using `counter + item`? `counter` is always `0`, and adding `0` doesn't change anything. Did you mean to assign to `counter` instead of `counter_item`?

Comment: `my_list` isn't a list, it's a string. `for item in my_list:` is iterating over each character in the string.

Comment: Thank You @Barmar, but can you apply what you mean to my code, and post it that way, its very hard for me to follow otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `split()` to split the input into a list.

Then, you need to test `isnumeric()` on every element of the list, not the whole string.

Call `int()` to convert the list elements to integers.

Finally, add the sum to `counter`, not `counter_item`.

```
my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n").split()
while not all(item.isnumeric() for item in my_list):
  print("\n----------------------------------------------------")
  print("***Sorry, what you had entered contained a letter.***")
  print("----------------------------------------------------\n")

  my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n").split()

counter = 0 
for item in my_list:
    counter = counter + int(item)
print(counter)
```

You don't need to use `else:` after the loop. That's only needed if the loop can end using `break`, and you want to run code only if it ends normally.

You don't need to use `int()` when printing, since `counter` is already an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isdigit()` instead of `.isnumeric()`, for checking if input is  solely numbers or not.

```
my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n")
while not my_list.isdigit():
  print("\n----------------------------------------------------")
  print("***Sorry, what you had entered contained a letter.***")
  print("----------------------------------------------------\n")

  my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n")
else:
  counter = 0 
  for item in my_list:
    counter +=int(item)
  print(counter)
```

Also, use `+=`. It will add the value instead of creating a local variable every time.

The error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"` states that it cannot add string and an integer.

- `+` between 2 strings is for string concatenation.
- `+` between 2 integers is for addition.

What you probably want to do is the second one.
So convert `s` to an integer

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are adding `str` and `int`. You need to convert `item` to `int` before adding in counter.

```
counter_item = counter + int(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert strings to ints (using the `int` function) before you can add them.  In addition, if your intent is to have the user enter multiple numbers, you probably want to `split()` the string before converting the numbers into ints -- which means you can't use `isnumeric()` on the original string to check for input errors, because it will contain spaces!

Here's how I'd do it:

```
while True:
    try:
        print(sum(map(
            int,
            input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n").split()
        )))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("\n----------------------------------------------------")
        print("***Sorry, what you had entered contained a letter.***")
        print("----------------------------------------------------\n")
```

This is a good example of the power of exceptions as an error handling mechanism -- instead of having to individually check each element of the list (as you would have to do in a language that doesn't support exceptions), you can just operate on the list under the assumption that everything will work, and use a single `try/except` to catch resulting `ValueErrors` no matter where they get raised in that process.  Putting the whole thing in a `while` loop lets you simply retry until the entire sequence of operations is able to finish with no exceptions.

Example output:

```
Input your list.(Numbers)
lskdjf

----------------------------------------------------
***Sorry, what you had entered contained a letter.***
----------------------------------------------------

Input your list.(Numbers)
1 2 3 4
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    input_lst = map(int,input("Enter list of number").split())
    try:
        counter = 0
        for val in input_lst:
            counter += int(val)
        break
    except Exception:
        print ("All the inputs were not numeric.")
print (counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

your are taking the input in wrong way, input writes a sring into My_list.

```
my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n").split(" ")
```

isnumaric function is applyed to integer data type but not for arry.
so you need to apply a for loop or while loop to check each element on arry.

counter is integer data type and item is string data type since input function  retuns string, so u need to convert string to int using `int()`function..
`counter_item = counter_item + int(item)`

i have made a code which may works for you.

```
my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n").split(" ")
print(my_list)
i =0
while i!= len(my_list):
  for item in my_list:
    if item.isnumeric():
      i+=1
      continue
    else:
      i=0
      print("\n----------------------------------------------------")
      print("***Sorry, what you had entered contained a letter.***")
      print("----------------------------------------------------\n")
      my_list = input("Input your list.(Numbers)\n").split(" ")
      break 
else:
  counter_item = 0 
  for item in my_list:
    counter_item = counter_item + int(item)
  print(int(counter_item))
```